# Magento payment gateway referrer

Tags: magento, payment, gateway

Are there any creative ways to find the exact referring URL for payments submitted by Magento? I'm using an extension for the MyVirtualMerchant gateway and so far it has not accepted any of the HTTP referrers I have entered (/checkout/onepage, etc).

Do extensions have their own URL structure when they actually send data behind the scenes?